# Where should I install a new format (.fmt file) to TeX?

Tags: format-files

I have the web2c version of TeX installed manually from texlive packages. I'm using Linux. The format is installed for my user and works if I put the .fmt file under ~/.texlive2014/texmf-var/web2c/tex/. But I want to install the format for all users.

Some kpathsea variables in my system which should be useful:

```
TEXMFMAIN=/opt/texlive/texmf-dist
TEXMFDIST=/opt/texlive/texmf-dist
TEXMFLOCAL=/opt/texmf-local
TEXMFSYSVAR=/opt/texlive/texmf-var
TEXMFSYSCONFIG=/opt/texlive/texmf-config
TEXMFVAR=/home/harry/.texlive2014/texmf-var
TEXMFCONFIG=/home/harry/.texlive2014/texmf-config
TEXMFHOME=/home/harry/texmf
VARTEXFONTS=/home/harry/.texlive2014/texmf-var/fonts
TEXMF={/home/harry/.texlive2014/texmf-config,/home/harry/.texlive2014/texmf-var,/home/harry/texmf,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-config,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-var,!!/opt/texmf-local,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-dist}
SYSTEXMF=/opt/texlive/texmf-var:/opt/texmf-local:/opt/texlive/texmf-dist
TEXMFDBS={!!/opt/texlive/texmf-config,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-var,!!/opt/texmf-local,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-dist}
WEB2C={/home/harry/.texlive2014/texmf-config,/home/harry/.texlive2014/texmf-var,/home/harry/texmf,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-config,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-var,!!/opt/texmf-local,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-dist}/web2c
TEXPSHEADERS=.:{/home/harry/.texlive2014/texmf-config,/home/harry/.texlive2014/texmf-var,/home/harry/texmf,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-config,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-var,!!/opt/texmf-local,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-dist}/{dvips,fonts/{enc,type1,type42,type3}}//
TEXCONFIG={/home/harry/.texlive2014/texmf-config,/home/harry/.texlive2014/texmf-var,/home/harry/texmf,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-config,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-var,!!/opt/texmf-local,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-dist}/dvips//
ENCFONTS=.:{/home/harry/.texlive2014/texmf-config,/home/harry/.texlive2014/texmf-var,/home/harry/texmf,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-config,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-var,!!/opt/texmf-local,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-dist}/fonts/enc//
TEXFONTMAPS=.:{/home/harry/.texlive2014/texmf-config,/home/harry/.texlive2014/texmf-var,/home/harry/texmf,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-config,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-var,!!/opt/texmf-local,!!/opt/texlive/texmf-dist}/fonts/map/{kpsewhich,pdftex,dvips,}//
```

I tried to install the file at /opt/texmf-local/web2c/tex/, /opt/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/web2c/tex/ and /opt/texlive/texmf-var/web2c/tex/, but it doesn't work. TeX complains "I can't find the format file".

I also tried to use "fmtutil-sys --all", but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Use `TEXMFLOCAL`, that is your first attempt; remember you have to also do `mktexlsr` (as superuser).

Comment: Yes! That was the problem! I missed `mktexlsr`. Thanks for the help. If you write this as an answer, I will mark as correct.